# Stop a command run from exec in java from "stealing" colors

Tags: java

as the title suggests i am having troubles with colors with exec, what i am trying to do:

a simple GUI to start/stop mc servers, but when i run the command

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

its not returning colors, though in the normal windows command prompt it returns colors just fine, i guess mc's color codes are the same for the command prompt and it is interpreting the colors as its own? The strange part for me is that it dosent return colors or color codes, just plain white text, i don't really need the text already colored, just the codes, here is what i got:

```
Process proc; // Process containing the server itself, i use this when stopping the server (stopping the server is not relevant but i tought id mention it)

File f = new File(path.getText()); // Path is a text field where i input the path to the server's folder
File bat = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "run.bat"); // The .bat file containing the command
String cmd = ""; // Command to be executed
if(dotbat.exists()) {
    cmd = bat.getAbsolutePath(); // Get the .bat with its path, resulting in the .bat file to be launched
} else {
    cmd = "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui" // The command in case the .bat file dosent exist
}
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, f); // Executing the command in the specified folder

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); // Reading the input stream

String s = null;
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\n" + s); // Append to the JTextPane the current line that the program is reading
}
```

To replicate this:

Put the code above in the main method of a java class, replace the part

```
String cmd = ""; // Command to be executed
if(dotbat.exists()) {
    cmd = bat.getAbsolutePath();
} else {
    cmd = "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui"
}
```

with:

```
cmd = "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui";
```

also replace:

```
File f = new File(path.getText());
File bat = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "run.bat");
```

with:

```
File f = new File("Path\to\your\server");
```

and lastly, replace:

```
textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\n" + s);
```

with:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

Note: in case you want to use a text pane, leave the

```
textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\n" + s);
```

and just rename the textPane if you have a diff name

The final code you should have after replacing is:

```
Process proc; // Process containing the server itself, i use this when stopping the server (stopping the server is not relevant but i tought id mention it)

File f = new File("Path\to\Your\Server"); // The path to your server
String cmd = "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui";
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, f); // Executing the command in the specified folder

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); // Reading the input stream

String s = null;
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\n" + s);
    System.out.println(s) // Use the line above if you want to use a text pane
}
```

Comment: why would you want to? That's a lot of effort you put into something that can easily cause problems if the user decides to use a terminal that uses colors differently.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you mean about "returning colors", but I don't know how we could help figure out why the "command" you're running (a separate Java program) is "stealing" them without seeing the code *for that program*. It's also not clear to me why you're doing things this way, rather than just importing some code and instantiating something and calling its methods.

Comment: i am running the default command for running a minecraft server, what i mean by stealing is that the windows command prompt is taking the color codes and coverting them for himself (the command prompt) and not returning like "&1" "&b" etc, so i am left with a white text with no color codes